# MagickCore writing image data to stdout rather than to a filename

Tags: c, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm using MagickCore to generate images from scratch. I'm trying to save my `Image` as a PNG file, but whenever I call `WriteImage`, it outputs to standard out rather than to the filename that I specified. For example:

```
Image *image = ImageGenerator(...); // generates valid image

ImageInfo *info = CloneImageInfo (NULL);
info->file = NULL;
strcpy (info->filename, "test.png");
strcpy (info->magick, "png");

WriteImage (info, image);
```

When this code is used, it outputs PNG data to standard out rather than to `test.png`. Is there something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick was to use the `FILE *` provided by the `ImageInfo` struct.

```
...
info->file = fopen ("test.png", "w+b");
strcpy (info->filename, "test.png");
strcpy (info->magick, "png");
...
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I was already doing this, but the problem was that I had opened the file in read-only mode.